# NodeJs request.get() function not working while the url is accessible from the browser

Tags: node.js, file, httprequest

I am using the `request` npm module.I want to retrieve an image from a url. The request.get(url) function is returning me a '400 Bad Request', whereas the image is accessible from the browser.

The url i am hitting is : `http://indiatribune.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/health.jpg`

Comment: please provide us with a sample of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add some headers:

```
const request = require('request');
request.get({
    url: 'http://indiatribune.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/health.jpg',
    headers: {

        Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,hu;q=0.4',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
        Host: 'indiatribune.com',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',

    },
}, (err, response, data) => {
    console.log(response, data);
});
```

The `User-Agent` seems to be enough.

Comment: Yes, it is working. Thank you. But i am more unsatisfied now. Why does other image urls dont require these headers?, How do i know which url will need which headers?, what is unique about this URL?, Which is the set of perfect headers which can be used for all get request, which does not arise such special cases?

Comment: It depends on the server which serves this image. In this case the server checks the headers, and sends responses accordingly. Probably the server does only want to serve images to browsers, and not bots. Most of web servers doesn't do this check.

Comment: Ok, I will add some generic header like this in my framework, so that i run into fewer problems like this. As it depends on the server code and checks, i don't think there is a permanent solution for problems like this. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Use [download module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download) . It's pretty simple.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const download = require('download');

download('http://indiatribune.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/health.jpg').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('foo.jpg'));
```

Comment: I have a framework written for this http and https interaction, which is generic irrespective of the data. I don think download module will fit into it.

Comment: Thank you for the info on the download module. It will be useful for me in the future.