# set user agent in a node request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I try to set user agent to a npm [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-request). Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers), but it gives the following error:

> Error: Invalid URI "/"

```
const request = require('async-request')

const run = async (url) => {
  const {statusCode} = await request(url)
  console.log(statusCode) // 200, works
  const options = {
    url,
    headers: { 
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36'
    }
  }
  await request(options) // Error: Error: Invalid URI "/"
}

run('https://github.com/')
```

[sandbox](https://repl.it/repls/PlasticSubtleList#index.js)

I also tried `request.get`, as it mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402099/nodejs-request-get-function-not-working-while-the-url-is-accessible-from-the-b), but it gives "request.get is not a function" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are looking at the documentation of [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), but using the [async-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-request), which dont support calling with the object argument like you do.

```
const request = require('async-request')

const run = async (url) => {
  const {statusCode} = await request(url)
  console.log(statusCode) // 200, works
  const options = {
    headers: { 
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36'
    }
  }
  
  const res = await request(url, options);  
  console.log(res.statusCode) // 200, works
}

run('https://github.com/')
```